# Draw circle in map using addresspiquer with google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-address

I'm using Address piquer map:

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker

This is the code of addrespicker library:

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/blob/master/src/jquery.ui.addresspicker.js

This library use google maps api v3 and I want draw in this map a circle.

The addrespicker code is:

```
        $(function () {
            var addresspickerMap = $("{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_addressAutocomplete' }}").addresspicker({
                map: map,
                regionBias: "es",
                mapOptions: {
                    zoom: {{ zoom | default(4) }},
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng({{ form.vars.data.address.lat | default(40.46366700000001) }}, {{ form.vars.data.address.lon | default(-3.7492200000000366)}}),
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                },
                elements: {
                    map: "#map",
                    lat: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_lat' }}",
                    lng: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_lon' }}",
                    street_number: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_streetNumber' }}",
                    route: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_street' }}",
                    locality: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_location' }}",
                    administrative_area_level_2: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_region' }}",
                    administrative_area_level_1: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_state' }}",
                    country: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_country' }}",
                    postal_code: "{{ '#' ~ form.vars.name  ~ '_address_zipcode' }}"
                }
            });

        var gmarker = addresspickerMap.addresspicker("marker");
        gmarker.setVisible(true);
        addresspickerMap.addresspicker("updatePosition");

});
```

I prove this code to draw circle but not works:

```
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: addresspickerMap.gmap,
            radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres
            fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
        circle.bindTo('center', gmarker.getPosition(), 'position');
```

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like:

```
 var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres
        fillColor: '#AA0000',
        center: gmarker.getPosition()
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I obtain this error: Uncaught Error: Value not valid to prooperty <map>: [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: that error message means nothing to me.  If you've copied that error message directly I'd say you've maybe got a typo in your code somewhere (`prooperty` not `property`?).  Update your question with all the map code together.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what this line is actually returning you: `var gmarker = addresspickerMap.addresspicker("marker");`  I assume a Google Marker object, which has a getPosition function.  But maybe it's something other than that, specific to the addresspicker plugin.  Regardless, to make a circle work, you need to specify a map and a center coordinates in the circleOptions